# How to display data inside object inside json/json using angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I get this JSON.

```
[
    {
        "id": 11,
        "parent_category": null,
        "name": "name11"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "parent_category": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "name11",
            "parent_category": null
        },
        "name": "name12"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "parent_category": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "name11",
            "parent_category": null
        },
        "name": "name13"
    }  
]
```

I want to show in view `parent_category.name` where `parent_category` is not null.

```
  <mat-select formControlName="parent_category">
                      <mat-option>--</mat-option>
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let p_g of mydata" [value]="p_g.id">
                        {{p_g.name}}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
```

Please, Can you share with me any idea how to show it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access internal object **`parent_category`**

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let p_g of mydata" [value]="p_g.id">
      {{p_g.parent_category?.name}}
 </mat-option>
```

Comment: This will render an "empty" option, which probably is not what OP wants.